# Convert integer to timestamp in PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, integer

I am creating a view in PostgreSQL. I have a table with a column `year` as type integer and want to convert it to a `timestamp without time zone` in new column with specific month/day, for example:

```
year | date
-----------
1999 | 1999-08-31
0    | 0
```

All years should have proceeding '08-31'

Currently, I have:

```
CASE When year > 0 Then concat(year, '-08-31') AND to_timestamp(year):: timestamp without time zone 
ELSE 0 END AS date
```

but that is a disaster....

Comment: There cannot be a timestamp 0. Would you prefer NULL or -infinity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
CASE WHEN year > 0 THEN
   CAST (format('%s-08-31', year) AS timestamp)
END
```

That will give you a NULL value for non-positive years.